# limit view area (viewport?) of s:TileGroup

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I have a s:TileGroup as follows:

```
                <s:TileGroup id="myTileGroup"
                     clipAndEnableScrolling="true" focusEnabled="true"
                     horizontalGap="4" 
                     paddingBottom="12" paddingLeft="12" paddingRight="2" paddingTop="12"
                     requestedColumnCount="3" requestedRowCount="3" verticalGap="4"
                     horizontalScrollPosition="12"
                     />
```

...resulting in a 3x3 grid TileGroup.

As items are added to the TileGroup it "overflows" its' bounds, items are displayed below, and when scrolled above, the 3x3 grid.

Is there a way to "mask" or otherwise hide these items?

I looking at the properties of TileGroup, I've tried to emplement the "verticalScrollPosition" and "bottom" properties - these don't do it.

Setting the "height" property effectively creates a bottom limit for the group, but when scrolled items are still displayed above the "padding" area.

Ideas anyone?

thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... well, I ended up resizing my surrounding borderContainer and it now effectively limits the TileGroup's items...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clip your content, you need to set explicit width/height (or use absolutes; left, right, top, bottom), or wrap it around a Scroller component.